# run unit tests on azure websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, mstest

I haven't been able to find anything straightforward that would allow me to run all the unit test projects in my solution as part of my deployment to azure. Can someone point me in the right direction please? I have looked at a couple of blog posts which modify the deploy.cmd to add in some scripting that targets specific dlls, but I was hoping for a more robust approach.

Comment: Have you considered uses of VSTS Build and Deployment system or another continuous integration system ?

Comment: @AbhaySaraf I have looked at Bamboo, but I was hoping to just do this in Azure itself.